# Telegram WebApp sendData method doesn't work on MacOS

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf

I am trying to figure out how to correctly work with WebApp added to Telegram API.

So, I have a simple setup of a React app and Bot. React app has counter and all I need is send counter data back to bot using [sendData](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps#initializing-web-apps) method.

Bot returns keyboard button, as mentioned in [telegram docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps#keyboard-button-web-apps) with link to my web-app

```
private async returnButton(ctx: Context<Update>): Promise<void | object> {
    ctx.reply('Enter number', Markup.keyboard([
          Markup.button.webApp('Open counter', 'https://75bc-185-115-37-241.eu.ngrok.io')
    ]).resize())
    return {};
}
```

Here's part of React app:

```
useEffect(() => {
    Telegram.WebApp.ready();

    Telegram.WebApp.MainButton.isVisible = true;
    setDebug(Telegram.WebApp.sendData.toString());
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
    Telegram.WebApp.onEvent('mainButtonClicked', () => {
        Telegram.WebApp.MainButton.text = 'Clicked!';

        try {
          Telegram.WebApp.sendData(JSON.stringify({ counter }));
          setDebug(`Sent`);
        } catch (e) {
          setDebug(`${e}, ${JSON.stringify(e)}`)
        }
    })
}, [counter])
```

> I've added `setDebug(Telegram.WebApp.sendData.toString())` just to
> make sure method is present. I didn't find any good ways for debugging, as I have no
> access to smth like devtools in webapp window

So below gif shows what happens when I click button on Mac client. Debug data set to `Sent` and no errors pops out. But modal doesn't close as it should and most importantly bot doesn't receive any data from webapp.

[image]

Though using iOS/ipadOS telegram flow works fine. Window closes and data sent to bot.

[image]

I have tried to reinstall Telegram client, but still no changes. Did I miss something or this is Mac client bug?

Comment: Just in case: I am using telegram-webapps-types so `Telegram.WebApp` is same as `window.Telegram.WebApp`

Comment: It seems like it is a bug, it is not working on my end as well.

Answer (score 2):

to get data from the main button you need to open the app with your keyboard. This will not work with an inline keyboard.